# How to insert single backslash in object string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I would like to understand how strings gets converted when getting assigned to an object. What would be the correct way to keep the single backslash in the string once it is declared in an object.

```js
let userId = 'domain\\username';
console.log(userId) // domain\username

let obj = {
  userId: userId
};
console.log(obj) // { userId: 'domain\\user' }
```

Bonus question: is it possible with a single backslash variable?

```
let obj = {
  userId: `domain\${userName}`
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two backslashes from `console.log`ging the object indicates that the string has *one* backslash. That is, you can see

```
"userId": "domain\\username"
```

and you can just copy and paste the string literal

```
const userId = "domain\\username"
```

and have that be equivalent to the `userId` property.

The base `userId`, when logged, doesn't have two backslashes because it's not printing a *string representation of a string in an object* - it's just printing a *string*.

This might be clearer if you check the *length* of the strings in question:

```js
let userId = 'a\\b';
console.log(userId);

let obj = {
  userId: userId
};
console.log(obj)

console.log(userId.length);
console.log(obj.userId.length);
```